# Button not correctly using resolution independent images

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios

I have an image with two sizes. x2 (40px) and x3 (60px).

Here is the XAML...

```
<Button
    Grid.Row="2"  
    Image="tick-white.png"
    Margin="8, 8, 8, 8"
    x:Name="btnSubmit"
    VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand"
    HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand"
    Text="CONFIRM"
    FontAttributes="Bold"
    TextColor="White"
    WidthRequest="150"
    HeightRequest="55" />
```

The results are unsatisfactory though...

- On iPhone X simulator, button text and image are correct.
- On iPhone 8 Plus simulator, image doesn't appear at all.
- On iPhone SE device, only image appears and it takes up the full
  height of the button.

So what do I do about this?

If I use a single image file without the @x2 and @x3 extensions then it works ok.

Comment: at the end it's better to create/use custom buttons, ex. create a clickable grid and put all your elements image/text inside

Comment: Did this particular image cause this issue? Can you try to test it with another image?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without a postfix on the filename, on a 2x screen, it seems to interpret, say, 40px x 40px as taking up 80px x 80px on the screen.

I added the "@2x" postfix to the 40px x 40px image's filename and the image appeared unpixelated but too small.

So I doubled the size to 80px x 80px and now it works.

Something like that...

So make sure you add the postfix.